# Find value if it exists in array

Tags: javascript

```
existe ([1,2,3],5)
false
existe ([1,2,3],2
true
```

I have a function called `existe` that receives an array and a number, how can I go through the array and know if that number is found

```
function existe (var arreglo, var numero){

}
```

Comment: Please note that the official language of Stack Overflow is English.

Comment: Note that there are both Spanish and Portuguese Stack Overflow exchanges: https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function existe(arreglo, numero) {
    return arreglo.indexOf(numero) !== -1;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Comment: This could have been a comment

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda, como le puedo hacer para que me devuelva un true si el numero esta en el arreglo y un false si el numero no se encuentra en el arreglo? function existe(var arreglo  = ["1","2","3"], var numero = 2 ){ }